# on_command_error not firing in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

`on_command_error` doesn't fire when met with a invalid command or CheckFailure. I just get printed a error in console as if it wasn't there.

```
AUTHORIZED_USERS = []
def is_authorized():
    async def predicate(ctx):
        return ctx.user.id in AUTHORIZED_USERS
    return app_commands.commands.check(predicate)

@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    print(error, ctx.user.id)

@tree.command(name="ping", description="Pong!")
@is_authorized()
async def ping(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Pong! :ping_pong:", description=f"Latency is `{str(round(client.latency, 4))}`.")
    await ctx.response.send_message(embed=embed)
```

I have looked over github, google, asked gpt. Can't find a thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `on_command_error` event will only be triggered if there's an error from a *prefix command*, not including app commands. For handling app command errors, you need to use the [tree.error](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.CommandTree.error) decorator.

Comment: Thanks so much! I hope this helps more people in the future!!